# Force scrollto then release

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to force window to scroll to a certain point if a variable is true, then once it scrolls there, I'd like to change the variable and release the window to scroll freely. How do I do this?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = 1
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        if(h == 1){
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('#next_div').offset().top}, 900, function(){
            var h = 2; }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( function () {
    var h = 1 ? ( $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#next_div').offset().top}, 900), h = 2 ) : 0;  
    console.log(h); // Optional for checking
});
```

Is same as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = 1
    if(h == 1){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('#next_div').offset().top}, 900, function(){
            h = 2; 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain your code a little and why mine wasn't working. Trying to absorb and learn here... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! You should have left $().scroll() out of your code, because it triggers it's function only after you have scrolled.